# media status is not giving any response actions on google/ Actions builder

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

As you can see I am playing the audio with MediaObject. Audio is playing but I am getting 'undefined' in mediaStatus

```
`app.handle('Default_Welcome_Intent', (conv) => {

    conv.add('This is a media response');
    conv.add(new Media({
        mediaObjects: [
            {
                name: 'Media name',
                description: 'Media description',
                url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/Jazz_In_Paris.mp3',
                image: {
                    large: ASSISTANT_LOGO_IMAGE,
                }
            }
        ],
        mediaType: 'AUDIO',
        optionalMediaControls: ['PAUSED', 'STOPPED'],
        startOffset: '0s'
    }));

    const mediaStatus = conv.intent.params.MEDIA_STATUS.resolved;
    return console.log(mediaStatus)
});`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time you're making the call, your intent handler has not yet completed. As such, the media hasn't begun playing by the time you're querying the media status. It's intentional that the status is unresolved by this point.

The media status will change later in the conversational flow. You'll want to read the documentation on [receiving media status](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-media#receiving_media_status) to your webhook at a later point in order to get the status and current media progress.